# Proposal: Include form for user that votes to close as "unclear" to clarify what is "unclear" and when edits clarify

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Where **the goal of closing a question is to revise and re-open**

Proposal: Include form for user that votes to close as "unclear" to clarify what is "unclear" and when edits clarify

- Vote to close "unclear what you're asking"
- 1) **Mandatory field(s):** Specify precisely what is "unclear" **to you** in the question

  2) **Button(s):**

  - Question is now clear -> vote towards re-opening
  - Question is not clear, refer to **field N**

User is reminded of "unclear what you're asking" queue for votes cast.

The same approach can be used for "off-topic" and "too broad" selected reasons for vote to close a question.

Solves: Avoidance of guessing what the vote to close as "unclear" is actually referring to **by that user** and provides a means to address specific issues as interpreted by that specific user.

The purpose of the feature is to be inclusive as possible as to the range of possible questions from different perspectives, and to address the specific issues with the question openly to improve the question for eventual re-opening.

Answer (score 14):

> Where the goal of closing a question is to revise and re-open

The first goal of closing a question is to keep people from posting answers to questions that are incomplete, unacceptable, or just too confused to answer. Yes, questions can be reopened, and that is a good thing. But closing is first and foremost a moderation act to preserve quality on the site.

This is the very reason why we don't require people to tether themselves to close votes or downvotes. That is, a person is not required to follow up to see if anything changed on any posts they've close/downvoted. That's a good thing. Time spent following up on an unclear question is time *not* spent answering a *clear* question.

Furthermore, I've seen plenty of questions closed as being unclear. I've seen very few of them with absolutely *no* comments under them asking for specific clarification. So, while it does happen, I don't think it happens frequently enough to be worth this feature.

Let people choose to make comments if they want to. And if they don't, so be it.